# $\gcd$ of polynomials over $F_p$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $K:=F_{p^{t}}$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Let $u\in K-F_p$. Prove that for all $n\ge1$ $\gcd(T^{2^{n}−2}+T^{2^{n}−4}+T^{2^{n}−8}+⋯+T^{2^{n}−2^{n−1}}+1,T−u)=1?$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote $F_p^t$? The product of $t$ copies of $F_p$?

Comment: Maybe $K:=F_{p^t}$ instead of $K:=F_p^{t}?$

Comment: yes, sorry!, it's an extension of $F_p$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct or is there something missing? For $n=2$ we get the polynomial $T^2+1$ which is a multiple of $T-u$ if $u$ is a square root of $-1$ which is not in $\Bbb F_p$ if $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$

Comment: This is wrong as stated. For any choice of $n$ the polynomial of degree $2^n-2$ splits over $\Bbb{F}_{p^t}$  for *some* $t$, and it won't split over the prime field for  all $p$. Therefore it will have a zero in $K$ for appropriate choice of $p,t$.

Comment: Thanks! leoli1 and  Jyrki Lahtonen